# How can I save settings in VI?

Tags: vi

I have changed tab settings in VI with `set tabstop=4`. But when I restart VI, the settings are restored. How can I save the settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create/edit a file named `.exrc` in your `/home/` directory and write your settings like this

`:set tabstop=4`